MultiWebsite Canonical Tag - Scope Website/WebStore
Magento lacks the feature to make one website canonical over another one.
Actually, we have got three websites:

https://foodentyco.it which is our default website
https://foodentyco.it/local which is our local website
https://foodentyco.it/international which is our international
website

The local website has got nearly the same contents as the national one, apart some specific offering aspects which would not make much difference for seo engines.
Indeed, google claims the local website being a duplication of the base one.
We were seeking for an extension which would enable us to make the canonical link at a website / webstore level, but we only found extensions for cms pages, products and categories.
Does anyone may help for addressing the topic?
